# How to use a button to show a custom dialog in android application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following a youtube tutorial and I've got most of the works done, but I still got some problems.

I have my custom layout for my custom dialog, all I wanted to do is to set the custom dialog on a button. Once we click the button ,the dialog shows, that's it. I've already set the onclicklistener on the button, here's my code.

```
Credit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Dialog credit = new Dialog(Main.this);
           credit.setContentView(R.layout.creditdialog);
           credit.setTitle(" ");
           credit.show();
        }
    });
```

I followed all of this on a tutorial, but I don't know that the "MAIN" is about, I got an error there. Please tell me what to do. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: instead of main use your activity... `YourActivity.this`

Comment: use `ActivityName.this` instead of Main

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I know this could be a noob question. Thank you very much.

Comment: this will help you http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/10/android-dialog-android-custom-dialog-for-user-login.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Dialog(Main.this);
```

The above line creates a new dialog object and associates it with the context of your Activity. SO you have to pass the context of your activity in the paranthesis..

Eg:

If you are calling the dialog from Activity "ActivityMain".. then use:

```
new Dialog(ActivityMain.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Credit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


         Dialog credit = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                     credit.setContentView(R.layout.creditdialog);
                     credit.setTitle(" ");
                      credit.show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it is common question! but you can extend dialog box and can set custom layout for your dialog than on button click just call dialog like this:
    new CustomDialog(activity).show();

also you can follow this tutorial on custom dialog to understand how to customise dialog and how to use it on button click.
http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/types-of-dialogbox-part-two-custom.html